# Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create saveOrUpdate event with null entity

Tags: java, hibernate, session, insert

I am trying to insert into database. I am posting my code below.

DAO class:

```
package com.persistent.progracers.data.dao;    

import org.hibernate.Session;
import com.persistent.progracers.data.pojo.UserDemographicInfo;

public class UserDemographicInfoDAO {
public void persist(UserDemographicInfo userDemographicInfo, Session session){
    session.save("UserDemographicInfo", userDemographicInfo);
}

public void update(UserDemographicInfo userDemographicInfo, Session session){
    session.saveOrUpdate("UserDemographicInfo", userDemographicInfo);
}

public void delete(UserDemographicInfo userDemographicInfo, Session session){
    session.delete("UserDemographicInfo", userDemographicInfo);
}

}
```

POJO class:

```
 package com.persistent.progracers.data.pojo;

 import java.util.Date;

 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UserDemographicInfo implements java.io.Serializable {

private long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Date dateOfBirth;
private String mobileNumber;
private String gender;
private String status;
private Address address;
private String employeeID;
private String bloodGroup;
private Date dateCreated;
private Date dateModified;

public UserDemographicInfo() {
}

public UserDemographicInfo(String firstName, String lastName,
        Date dateOfBirth, String mobileNumber, String gender,
        String status, Address address, String employeeID,
        String bloodGroup, Date dateCreated, Date dateModified) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.status = status;
    this.address = address;
    this.employeeID = employeeID;
    this.bloodGroup = bloodGroup;
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    this.dateModified = dateModified;
}

public long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Date getDateOfBirth() {
    return this.dateOfBirth;
}

public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}

public String getMobileNumber() {
    return this.mobileNumber;
}

public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
    this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
}

public String getGender() {
    return this.gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return this.status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Address getAddress() {
    return this.address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getEmployeeID() {
    return this.employeeID;
}

public void setEmployeeID(String employeeID) {
    this.employeeID = employeeID;
}

public String getBloodGroup() {
    return this.bloodGroup;
}

public void setBloodGroup(String bloodGroup) {
    this.bloodGroup = bloodGroup;
}

public Date getDateCreated() {
    return this.dateCreated;
}

public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
}

public Date getDateModified() {
    return this.dateModified;
}

public void setDateModified(Date dateModified) {
    this.dateModified = dateModified;
}

}
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                     "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory name="SessionFactory">
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin123</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ngo</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">ngo</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<mapping resource="com/persistent/progracers/data/pojo/UserDemographicInfo.hbm.xml"/>
```

Now the problem is I am using WaveMaker Studio..It creates one Java Service. So the Java Service Code is here :

```
import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.persistent.progracers.data.dao.UserDemographicInfoDAO;
import com.persistent.progracers.data.pojo.UserDemographicInfo;
import com.persistent.progracers.wecare.factory.HibernateSessionFactory;


public class UserRegistrationService extends com.wavemaker.runtime.javaservice.JavaServiceSuperClass {
/* Pass in one of FATAL, ERROR, WARN,  INFO and DEBUG to modify your log level;
 *  recommend changing this to FATAL or ERROR before deploying.  For info on these levels, look for tomcat/log4j documentation
 */
public UserRegistrationService() {
   super(INFO);
}

public UserDemographicInfo sampleJavaOperation(UserDemographicInfo demopojo) {
   UserDemographicInfoDAO demodao=new UserDemographicInfoDAO();

   Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
   try {
      log(INFO, "Starting sample operation");
      demodao.persist(demopojo, session);
      log(INFO, "Returning ");
   } catch(Exception e) {
      log(ERROR, "The sample java service operation has failed", e);
   }
   return demopojo;
}

}
```

There is one service variable in wavemaker which binds all the values to the table's related fields.But It gives me Error when I click on save button

> :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create saveOrUpdate event with null entity.

StackTrace :

```
INFO (JavaServiceSuperClass.java:155) 22:41:25 - Starting sample operation
ERROR (JavaServiceSuperClass.java:131) 22:41:26 - The sample java service operation     has failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create saveOrUpdate event with null     entity
   at org.hibernate.event.SaveOrUpdateEvent.(SaveOrUpdateEvent.java:40)
   at org.hibernate.event.SaveOrUpdateEvent.(SaveOrUpdateEvent.java:23)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
   at       com.persistent.progracers.data.dao.UserDemographicInfoDAO.persist(UserDemographicInfoDAO.java:8)
 at UserRegistrationService.sampleJavaOperation(UserRegistrationService.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.wavemaker.runtime.service.reflect.ReflectServiceType.invokeMethod(ReflectServiceType.java:122)
at com.wavemaker.runtime.server.ServerUtils.invokeMethodWithEvents(ServerUtils.java:303)
at com.wavemaker.runtime.server.ControllerBase.invokeMethod(ControllerBase.java:269)
at com.wavemaker.runtime.server.JSONRPCController.executeRequest(JSONRPCController.java:123)
at com.wavemaker.runtime.server.ControllerBase.handleRequestInternal(ControllerBase.java:125)
at  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.jav a:153)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:788)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:717)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:143)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
```

Can anyone please tell me whats the mistake here?

Comment: a line number would be very helpful.

Comment: Post the method that's called on the "click on save button", also the rest of the stacktrace. You can remove the entity definition.

Comment: @βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ I've posted it. On save button's click event service variable is called which is bind with the above mentioned java service class..

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
 public UserDemographicInfo sampleJavaOperation(UserDemographicInfo demopojo) {
   UserDemographicInfoDAO demodao=new UserDemographicInfoDAO();
```

and here

```
demodao.persist(demopojo, session);
```

*UserDemographicInfo demopojo* is null.

That code calls :

```
public void persist(UserDemographicInfo userDemographicInfo, Session session){
    session.save("UserDemographicInfo", userDemographicInfo);
}
```

and throws the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.But I've just retrieved values from demopojo before persist. and its not null.

Comment: Yes. I am confused now.Even my current stacktrace is showing these msgs. 1. INFO - Starting sample operation. 2. INFO -Values inserted by user at runtime 3.INFO-Returning. But still values are not inserted into the database.I am not getting why?